# Why is this specific answer not a "Not An Answer"?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer, specific-answer

The answer in question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54868858/5779732.

[image: Quoted: "And note that you named your binding variable inflate but you use binding.getRoot() in the return statement. So rename your variable to binding. Or change your return statement to return inflate.getRoot(); Whatever you prefer." then the following text: "I was with the same problem and this worked for me."]

This answer is a part (quote) copied from [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46297231/5779732) for same question. The only additional thing it says is:

> I was with the same problem and this worked for me.

So, it looks like that this user was having same issue, he googled and found this question and accepted answer (part of it may be) helped him. Good.

So, this user is happy because accepted answer saved his day. Ideal thing to do here is to up-vote accepted answer. Instead, he copies relevant part from accepted answer and posts a new answer adding *comment like text* saying this helped me.

I commented on the answer as below:

> This is commentary on other answer; not an answer. Upvote is better choice if allowed. – Amit Joshi

Then I flagged this as NAA; flag declined.

[image: The flag: "declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"]

Why is this answer not a "Not An Answer"?

Comment: Say "Plagiarism".

Comment: @JL2210: I don't think so. Plagiarism is _intentional_. This is not. This is due to lack of understanding of how site works.

Comment: True. The moderator didn't notice that this was in a quote, though, and might have thought that the answer was original.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yeah, this was my mistake. I was handling the flag on mobile, and I saw the post as a clear answer without the quotes.

<s>I don't know for what reason (I wasn't drunk, that's for sure), perhaps it was because of Twilight brightness app on the phone, I didn't see that the first part was quoted. Enough of blaming the tool, when the problem was with the one using it.</s>

I figured it out. There is another flag in the queue, now, which has similar characteristics. In the mod queue, the markdown is completely stripped. Therefore the answer would have appeared as a whole one, something like:

> And note that you named your binding variable inflate but you use binding.getRoot() in the return statement. So rename your variable to binding. Or change your return statement to return inflate.getRoot(); Whatever you prefer. I was with the same problem and this worked for me.

(without the quotes, obviously). That's the reason why I saw the post as a clear answer without the quotes. In hindsight, I probably should be opening each answer and checking it. This one is one of the very corner cases. Sorry again.

Here's how it looks like in the mod tools:

[image]

Therefore, even if I was on a laptop I probably would have declined it. Using a mobile wasn't the culprit here.

I am sorry for the decline. It was a correct flag.

Comment: You are [missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310352/400849) something in answer we want paper bag in this answer

Comment: I always wear a paper bag on my head...

Comment: Thanks; we are all human and we _have_ to use technology (mobile) though it creates problems sometime. So no need to say sorry.

Comment: Is there a way to change the status of that flag to helpful now?

Comment: Nope, @AmitJoshi, we can't change the status of flags retroactively.

Comment: I thought the long-standing rule for NAA flags was “strip away the markup”, then see if they’re an answer. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray, that is for link only answers.

Comment: @BhargavRao you probably just need a break. I've seen you all over the place like no time else lately. And yes, stay away from mobile apps: they generally suck

Comment: *"In the mod queue, the markdown is completely stripped"* - wait, what? This is obviously the root problem; it seems inevitable that it'll produce outcomes precisely like this one. This is one of the recurring moments where an offhand mod comment gives me a glimpse into the crapness of (at least some of) the mod tools and my mind swivels in confusion.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, I'm back from a 3 month break, which ended last November. Also, I've not even reached half my potential ;) ... that said, lemme know if you feel that I probably should step away.  :)

Comment: @MarkAmery, I wouldn't blame the mod tools. This was a corner case, if it was above 200 characters long (w/o the markdown), then I would have opened the post to check it. I will share an image of how it would have looked, sometime later in the day.

Comment: @Mark Yes, I personally feel like the post display in the moderator flag dashboard is almost completely useless. I never expand the preview. Instead, I *always* click through to view the post itself in context. Not only does this allow me to see it as the author intended, but it also allows me to deal with the question (which is often partly to blame for attracting low-quality answers). It takes a few seconds more to handle each flag, but having that expanded context is well worth it to me.

Comment: _"Here's how it looks like in the mod tools:"_ Is this considered a bug? It certainly should be.

Comment: *Flashbacks* - Almost similar stuff happened again https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949641/4099593

Answer (score 7):

Whenever flagging a post, ask yourself, "How will this look out of context?" If it isn't *immediately* clear why your flag reason is applicable, consider a custom flag so you can explain the context.

Even with the quote markup, it's not immediately clear that the quote is from another answer on the same question. It could just as easily be a case of a missing citation. I would have used a custom flag and noted that it was doing nothing more than quoting another answer. More clarity, less confusion, less chance of error.

If SO doesn't want us using custom flags that way, then it should improve the mod and review interfaces to provide more context. With the tools as is, this is an unfortunate necessity.

Comment: I can't speak for other moderators, but I appreciate the custom flags in any case where you think more clarity/context would be illuminating. Any time you save me from having to scratch my head and wonder what the flagger was thinking, that's a good thing. I wouldn't blame the moderator tools as much as I'd blame the fact that we have humans doing the moderating.

Comment: @CodyGray In that case, we might blame the flagging tools for not allowing us to provide more context with *all* flag types. I still maintain there's a tooling problem somewhere because custom flags seem to be discouraged when other flags are applicable. I think part of the reason for that is because some of the other flags kick it to review queues so moderators don't necessarily have to handle them.

Comment: Well, it's basically just that there's no need to use a custom flag for a "Thanks, this helped me!" answer. Just a bog-standard NAA flag is sufficient there because it's so obvious, and easier for us to deal with. We also don't want custom flags that say "please close this question" because (A) it doesn't tell us *why* it needs to be closed, and (B) using a standard flag allows the community to help handle these. I mean, the tooling is definitely not perfect. If SE gave me the keys to the code base, there's a few things I'd change. But it's not quite as bad as you seem to be implying, either.

Comment: @CodyGray I think it's more frustrating for users, really. These kinds of "flag declined" posts are not particularly uncommon on Meta, even if they're a very small percentage of handled flags. I kind of like the idea of being able to optionally add details for all flag types now that I'm thinking about it, but I doubt SO would bother doing it. It's frustrating that SO has sunk pretty much no effort into any moderation tools in the past few years, and that frustration is probably part of what you're picking up on. I'm concerned that the tooling isn't keeping up with problems as the site grows.

Comment: If you saw *most* of the custom moderator flags we get, you would be a little less excited about the idea of giving everyone a textbox to fill in. :-) It isn't the diamond moderator tools that need more love/attention. It's the community moderation tools. They don't scale to keep up with the large volume of garbage. You'll never get a handful of moderators to scale to that level, that's why we have community moderation by trusted users in the first place. So, I sympathize with the general frustration here, as anyone who follows my recurring snark on Meta can attest.

Comment: @jpmc26 How are you merely "concerned" that the tooling hasn't kept up? Posts like this are direct evidence that it *absolutely has not kept up*.

Comment: @IanKemp Forgive me for choosing charitable language for once. =p

Comment: @jpmc26 Sorry, I wasn't meaning to attack you, it's just that I get so angry when a company that relies on *unpaid staff* to do their work for them, doesn't even have the decency to provide said staff with decent tools.

Comment: @IanKemp It's okay. I agree. I think the reality is they don't want us to do that work. They believe it's unjust and discriminatory to reject content based on quality.