# Please help with my missing question on meta

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, meta

I remember I asked a question on meta after 26-Feb-2019. I am not able to find that question. It is not showing up in Deleted Recent Questions as well.

I do not remember but may be I deleted it myself; very less possibility though. Otherwise, it might have been deleted by someone else for some reason or maybe roomba'd.

It was tagged [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion), and was about allowing moderators to change flag status. I do not remember whether it had any answers. Its title was *something* like: "Should we allow moderators to change the flag status after flag is declined incorrectly"; do not remember exact text.

Can someone with enough privileges un-delete that question if found and if possible?

It is not "absolutely necessary" to un-delete it. If not possible to un-delete, please just comment why it was deleted.

Comment: I imagine you remember asking two meta questions on Feb 26, right? Because [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380633/why-is-this-specific-answer-not-a-not-an-answer) has not been deleted. Just in case. :P

Comment: @yivi: The question I am looking for was triggered based on one of the comments in your linked question. I remember I asked it may be around in a week after that question.

Comment: Do you remember if your other question was closed/downvoted? If it was, the most likely scenario is that fellow users >10k simply voted to delete the question. There are some users quite proactive on question deletion around in meta.

Comment: @yivi: Sorry; I do not remember votes on that question. I asked that question and initial signal was against the request. Also, my query was answered in comments. So I neglected that question then after. So; I did not monitored the votes.

Comment: Here you go: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380659/should-a-feature-to-change-the-flag-status-after-handling-the-flag-be-provided-t

Comment: @yivi It turns out it was closed as a duplicate and then roomba'd. A similar thing once happened with a [feature-request] of mine once (that one hadn't been closed as a duplicate, but AFAIK the roomba treats duplicates the same as open questions).

Comment: Thanks @Rob: No need to un-delete it. I hope your comment will not be deleted in future. Thanks for efforts and support.

Comment: It's a pity that searches for your own deleted stuff only work at 10k+

Comment: maybe flagging one of your meta posts for moderator would be enough. I could find your post in a few seconds. Not very convenient to reply to you in the "helpful" comment, though, not sure flagging is allowed to request information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Rob♦ for help. As he [commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386391/please-help-with-my-missing-question-on-meta#comment705650_386391) under question [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380659/5779732) is the question I was looking for. No need to un-delete it.

Thanks to everyone again for help and support.