# Not an answer flag declined even though they were asking a new question

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I recently flagged this answer as not being an answer

[SQL - CASE STATEMENT - WHEN statement AND statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928474/sql-case-statement-when-statement-and-statement/17871283#17871283)

This was declined with

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

The original answer had the line

> Is the query below correct?

and then went on the add the code.

This to me would make it a new question and therefore not an answer. The person that edited the question just removed the question at the start making is seem like an answer even though it doesn't attempt to answer the question posed.

My question is should this flag have been accepted, should I have flagged this a different way or was I wrong to flag it at all?

Comment: You could also interpret "Is the query below correct?" as some form of "Try this:" where the answerer seeks confirmation from the OP whether the code works for them.

Comment: The answer does not even have the related names of the original question, In my view, it should not be considered as an answer.

Comment: @honk I did consider that but the answer doesn't relate to the question nor attempt to answer it. So yes, that could be the case in some answers but I don't think it applies here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did not handle this flag, but I'm not surprised your flag was declined. Because it is easily missed that the post was edited to remove the initial 'Is the query below correct?` line, as that edit was  made **6 years ago**:

> edited Jul 26 '13 at 1:26

When a moderator looks at the NAA flag dashboard, the context with the flag and answer is updated to add an *edited* marker, but only if a post was edited *after flagging*. While we can find out when a post was last edited by expanding the answer in the dashboard, we don't normally would even look at edits that far back. As it is, to the moderator that handled this flag, this post looked like a straight-forward attempt at answering, and so declined your NAA flag.

Note that it *doesn't matter* that to a subject expert looking more closely can spot that this query has very little in common with the question; we are not all subject experts, and the number of flags we handle each day don't leave us with much time to examine every answer in detail, nor would we *want* to expend much time on these flags.

I've now rolled back the bad edit and deleted the answer, *but in future*, when you come across a post that has been edited this far back a custom 'moderator attention' flag would be much more effective. Something along the lines of

> This is not an answer, but a question that has since been edited to remove the question portion. That edit was wrong, and what remains is still not an answer. Please remove it.

Custom flags are there for the exceptions, this is one of those.

Comment: "and the number of flags we handle each day don't leave us with much time to examine every answer in detail." Maybe it's time for more meat for the grinder.

Comment: '*and the number of flags we handle each day don't leave us with much time to examine every answer in detail.*' - I'm not knocking anyone for this, ya'll do a great job, but, this IMHO, doesn't seem like a valid reason.

Comment: Let me qualify this further then: we are not going to examine every answer in detail. The NAA flag is designed for the *obvious cases*, of which there are plenty. Doing more is just a waste of a lot of time, where we can instead ask the community to put in a little bit of time into a custom flag.

Answer (score 4):

I declined your flag.

The reason why I declined your flag is very similar to what Martijn mentions, but a very slight difference. I did open the post in a new tab. I usually open all the posts completely and check it once before declining the flag. (Mark Amery might call me slow witted, but I do say that I open every post before declining a flag, especially since [this incident](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380635/4099593).)

The answer was a code only answer, and was downvoted. I saw that the post was edited ages ago, and therefore didn't feel the need to check its revisions. After that I declined the flag and moved on. Something which would have helped me to decide better here would have been to:

- Either use a custom flag (preferred - since you don't have the 2k editing privs) to indicate that the answer was a NAA but later edited to a code-only answer.
- Or roll it back to the version that was a NAA and then flag as NAA.

---

On a related note, lemme tell you a small story. A couple of years back when I was a normal user flagging NAAs, I noticed that a user had copied another answer completely and then added a thank you note. Something like this:

> ["{}{}".format(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)] this works. thank you

This was a clear NAA to someone who sees the post and the other answer. But if you had seen just the answer as it is, you can edit it to make it a valid answer.

> This works for me:
>
> ```
> ["{}{}".format(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
> ```

and so you can guess the outcome of the NAA flag on the post. From then on, I did start to make sure of editing the NAA post to a proper NAA and then flagging as NAA (and it did work wonders). For e.g: that post can be edited to:

> As Dave mentions: ["{}{}".format(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)] this works. thank you

which is a perfect NAA, and all the edit does is just add attribution to the copied part. So the lesson here is that we just need to make it clear that the post is a NAA, because the moderator on the other side of the computer would have no idea what your thought was while flagging the post.

---

Now to address the other concerns in the other answers. 1. Servy mentions that it was a rhetorical question, posted as an answer.

I can totally see where Servy is coming from, but I am on the fence here. The entire question is:

> Is the query below correct?

Which can possibly be rephrased to:

> Does this query work for you?

which would be a totally valid rhetorical question, and I would have declined the flags there asking users to not flag such posts for deletion. However, the sentence itself is very confusing and can be interpreted as "I have written the following query and I don't know if it is correct, can someone help me?". We do get a lot of questions that ask for help to execute the code that they have written and this might have been one of them.

It is very similar to the case of code-only self-answers, where we have no idea whether it should be an update to the question or an actual answer. I usually leave a comment on those:

> This answer, as-is is slightly unclear and needs to be clarified in order for it to become a valid solution to this question. Please do [edit] the answer, and flag for undeletion once you have clarified as to how it is a proper answer to the question.

Given the fact that the question already had a lot of other valid answers, the answer itself being downvoted to negative 3 and not being nowhere similar to the other answers, as well as the problem that the user was unregistered, there doesn't seem to be a strong reason to pass this answer as a valid rhetorical-question-as-answer to the post, and deleting it as a NAA would be a better choice.

---

... and finally regarding the concerns about the moderator queue being too huge, I have to vehemently disagree. In the 3 months from April 1st to June 30th, moderators on Stack Overflow had kept the queue close to 0 and touching 0 at least once every week. We had handled almost 200,000 flags with an average waiting time of just over half an hour. The problem here was with the post itself, and that NAA wasn't supposed to be used here, atleast not without clarifications.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I will use more appropriate flags in future.

Answer (score 1):

This post is not "Not An Answer".  It's an attempt to answer the question.  That the answer once [included a rhetorical question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300987/should-we-avoid-rhetorical-questions-in-answers) asking if the solution is a good idea doesn't mean it's not an answer.  It in fact makes it clear that it is *proposing a solution*, in that it's asking for feedback on it. It's just not a useful statement to include, which is why it was *correctly* removed by someone six years ago, as it's simply not a useful addition to the answer.

Comment: Small nitpick - I wouldn't call "Is this query correct?" in an answer a *rhetorical* question. I think it's a very *real* question expecting an answer from OP either in the form of an upvote, an accept mark, a comment, or all three.

Comment: @TylerH I wouldn't be so sure.  Lots of people include things like that, or "try this", or "I think this would work" or other types of qualifiers to their answer.  I don't necessarily think the author was expecting someone to provide some detailed critique of their answer.  But regardless, even if you don't think it was rhetorical, asking for feedback on *their answer to the question* still means it's an answer to the question.  And of course regardless that request for feedback can be removed if it's not useful, as is the case here, and as was done here, leaving just the answer.

Comment: @servy I don't think that is correct. If it was a question saying to try something or would this work then I would agree with that. However the code that remained wasn't related to the question posed and because of that it was likely the person was asking a separate question.

Comment: Sorry, in this case, this was **not** a rhetorical question. They really were asking for feedback if they had interpreted the other actual answers to implement this for their own query. The query they posted used an entirely different schema from the question subject, as well as different conditions for the CASE (using `>` greater than versus 3 possible compound tests).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Like I said, even if you don't interpret it as rhetorical, asking for feedback on your *answer to the question* is still an answer to the question, and the request for feedback can simply be removed as unnecessary.  Someone providing a solution to the same underlying problem, but with slightly different details in the specifics, doesn't make it not an answer.  It's still an answer to the problem being asked about.

Comment: @Servy: sorry, no, this was a new question, very badly worded.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, no, this was an answer to the question, very badly worded.

Comment: @Servy: don't be glib please, this is not going to go anywhere at this rate. How much SQL do you know? I can see that that query has issues, such as the embedded quotes. They never properly state why they are uncertain about their interpretation, but that's already a red flag right there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So it's okay for you to be glib, just not for anyone else?  Why is that?  If you want to keep this conversation on track then don't try to derail it yourself and blame me for it being derailed.  Stay on topic and address the merits, and I'll be happy to do the same.  That you see issues with they query doesn't mean it's not an answer.  If you think it's a bad answer, then by all means, downvote it.  That doesn't make it Not An Answer.    Moderators are not expected use judge answers based on their quality or accuracy and delete them if they feel they're not good.

Comment: @Servy: Despite your "not not an answer answer" assertion, it's still not a great answer.  Bare code, with no explanation provided.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that's Servy's point, it, not being a "not a great answer" implies is *is* an answer, voting should used here.

Comment: @Script47: No, I don't think so.  There's a "threshold effect" to flags; to justify undeletion, the material would have to "make the internet better," and I'm not convinced at all that's the case here.

Comment: @Servy: note that moderators are explicitly the *exception handlers* of the site. We are given the leeway to cut Gordian knots in case of ambiguous cases. This is such a case, and in my opinion as a moderator and as someone with a reasonable level of SQL experience, it was posted as a question. Hence my assertion: *sorry, no, this was a new question*. And I'm going to leave the discussion with that, this has now wasted way, *way* too much time. Even if treated as an answer, it is a pretty crappy answer anyway and not worth undeleting when there are much better answers there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Moderators are not expected to be judging the quality and technical merits of answers and deleting answers that they don't think are quality answers.  It's not your place to delete every answer that you don't think is helpful.

Comment: @Servy While moderators are not *expected* to be able to judge answers on their quality/technical merits and then deleting them if they don't think so, they *are* given the power and authority to do so if they so choose. They aren't required to only use their mod powers in response to a flag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're the one asserting it's an answer, just a poor answer.  So it's *not* ambiguous.  It *is* an answer, and thus it's not appropriate to delete it on the grounds that it's a non answer when *that's just not true*.  If you think it's a low quality answer, by all means, use your votes to reflect that.

Comment: @TylerH Do you have some citation that moderators are allowed to delete answers based on their technical merits just because they think they're not good answers?  Obviously they can use their mod powers on posts that aren't flagged (if a post requires moderation action), that's not in dispute.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, perhaps there is a terminology issue here then. The term *answer* can reference two distinct concepts: an 'answer post' (distinct from 'question posts' and 'comments' and other content types), and 'answering the question'. I was referring to the former meaning, not the latter.

Comment: @Servy I don't have anything specific, but the fact that it isn't expressly prohibited by rules, happens all the time and hasn't been decided against by CMs or the community, and is covered in powers & duties put forth by Jeff such as "Moderator votes are binding." and "culling some of the worst rated posts in various dimensions." in https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/ indicate it's within the scope of the mod position to do so. At any rate, this instance is really moot as Martijn was only the 3rd person to cast a delete vote on an answer that was already at -3 score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But it *is* providing an answer to the question, just one that you don't think is of high quality.    That you (and others) keep arguing about how it's not a *good* answer is demonstrating that it *is* an answer to the question.

Comment: @TylerH I don't really buy the argument that because moderators are allowed to deleted posts that they're free to delete whatever they want for any reason.  That seems like a rather unreasonable interpretation of the phrase "moderator votes are binding".  The rules state what types of posts *should* be deleted.  That "a moderator thinks it isn't a good answer" isn't described as meriting deletion doesn't mean it's okay to delete answers for that reason.  You need a reason *to* delete an answer, not a reason to *not* delete an answer.

Comment: @Servy I wouldn't buy that argument either. Luckily that's not the argument I gave. Martijn thought the answer was low quality. Users with 20k rep can vote to delete answers once they're at a sufficiently negative score. Martijn has more than 20k rep and cast the third of three required votes. The only issue here is that you aren't able to cast an undelete vote because Martijn is also a moderator and mod-deleted answers can't be undelete-voted by normal users. So, do you wish to undelete this answer? If so, that's a separate issue from whether the answer is NAA or not.

Comment: @TylerH How is it a separate issue that a moderator deleted an answer by claiming that it's not an answer when it isn't, preventing anyone who thinks it is an answer from undeleting it?  Martijn can't change the fact that they're a moderator, and thus they're acting as a moderator when they do things, and are not a 20k user.